# my findViewByID is thowing error?

Tags: android

My findViewById is throwing error saying it has not been defined and it asks me to create a function. What should I do?

```
public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
    hideSoftKeyboard(v);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String location = et.getText().toString();
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(context, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    double lat = add.getLatitude();
    double lng = add.getLatitude();
    gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title(locality).position(new LatLng(lat,lng));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


}
```

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: Is this method inside an `Activity`...?

Answer (score 0):

In your function find id like this

```
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

You havve to use the View variable passed in the method to find id

Comment: yes and if it is not then there should be no error in finding id

Comment: @RamIndani from question it is understandable that editext is part of View

Comment: Yes I totally agree, I was just trying to give little extra detail as user who asked question seems to be new Android developer.